# How to take first and second part of custom symbol in the words

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to separate a words in oracle column which is having 'MAT CHAMPAIGN - SOUTH---->MAT EP - KK'

i tried the below code to get

select regexp_substr('MAT CHAMPAIGN - SOUTH---->MAT EP - KK','([^,--->]+)',1,1) from dual : output is MAT CHAMPAIGN

select regexp_substr('MAT CHAMPAIGN - SOUTH---->MAT EP - KK','([^,--->]+)',1,2) from dual : output is SOUTH

actually i am trying to get  MAT CHAMPAIGN - SOUTH in one col and MAT EP - KK as a second column based on the symbol --->

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(.*)---->', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS first,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '---->(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS second
FROM yourTable;
```

Here we are using a regular expression to match and capture everything either before or after the `---->` separator.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
  regexp_substr('MAT CHAMPAIGN - SOUTH---->MAT EP - KK','^(.+?)---->',1,1, '', 1)col1
, regexp_substr('MAT CHAMPAIGN - SOUTH---->MAT EP - KK','---->(.+?)$',1,1, '', 1)col2 
from dual ;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.